# how to close the frame i cant find the elemen for x button - python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

How can i close the pop up I cant find the element for x button. i tried to inspect the element for it but it just x

[image]

and im also trying to switct frame but im getting an error

```
frame = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("hidden_iframe"))
```

[image]

[image]

this is what im seeing when I inspect this popup

[image]

Comment: `WebDriverWait(browser,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*["]')))`

Comment: i did but im still getting the error, im not sure if my script for switching to frame is correct

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[.='x']"))).click()
```

Try waiting and clicking the x span element.

Comment: im still getting the error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johnnatividad/PycharmProjects/Weedproject/venv/searchcheckout.py", line 30, in <module>
    frame = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("hidden_iframe"))
  File "/Users/johnnatividad/PycharmProjects/Weedproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: im not sure if im using the correct id name for that iframe.... iedit my  post I attached the screenshots at the bottom part

Comment: do I  need to switch frame?

Comment: Doesn't look like it's in the frame.

Comment: i was able to find now the right frame no.. thanks for the help :)